# GIMP: How can I control the "tolerance" of a tool?

Tags: gimp

On this image:

[image]

When I choose the "Select by Color Tool," it highlights all the black regions,

[image]

I only want it to choose the "slightly" black regions (which is the background), in another painting program (its name is paint.NET) there's this "tolerance" bar:

[image]

Does GIMP also have it? I want it so I can decrease the tolerance to a certain extent so that it only highlights the "slightly black" regions.

Comment: Yes there's a threshold slider in the tool options, but what is the ultimate goal of your edit? You may find there is a better solution if you explain your actual problem and show the original starting image. Can you edit your question to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Tool Options* dockable dialog the options for the currently selected tool are shown. After picking the *Fuzzy Select Tool* there is a slider labeled *Threshold* which has a similar function.

If you cannot see this dockable dialog it can be enabled through *Windows* → *Dockable Dialogs* → *Tool Options*.

[image: Threshold slider]

Comment: I tried it and it also picked all the black regions, have any other way?

Comment: If you want to select the partially transparent pixels, note that they have the same color - black - but a different alpha value.

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the real problem? Each time I see this kind of question popping up it is someone trying to handle anti-aliasing pixels. Maybe should you have a look at [this](  https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Background-removal-or-replacement-on-text-logos-and-other-computer-graphics).